# Creating multiple instances of feature set using Dagger2 instead of @Singleton

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a set of Fragments and ViewModels that use a shared dependency (`ProfitStore`) that is injected with Dagger2. Previously this dependency was marked `@Singleton` in its provider. This worked fine since there was only one way this feature could be launched, but now we need to be able to launch this feature from another portion of the app. There could be two instances of the `ProfitStore` being used at the same time because the user could switch between the two different versions using the application tabs. I can't understand how I am suppose to scope this dependency to these different features since my application only has one Activity.

I have seen some posts about creating "Feature Scopes" but this is only to compartmentalize this dependency graph. Not to be able to create two separate instances of the exact same dependency graph.

[image: Visual diagram]

Comment: Would you please include your diagram here, not refferring to an an external source?

Comment: I updated the question with the diagram. I kept getting an error back when trying to embed an image in the question, but now its working.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in Dagger, but can be a little bit tricky. A custom feature scope might be more trouble than it's worth, but if you have several interconnected objects with the same conceptual scope it might still be worthwhile.

This answer will first discuss custom scopes in general, then compare that choice with built-in fragment components in dagger.android and  Hilt (which you might or might not be using). At the end, I'll offer an alternative solution where you partially manage instances yourself.

### Scopes

First of all, we have to answer: what's the point of scopes? Conceptually, when you're asking Dagger for an instance of something stateful without providing a scope, the assumption is that Dagger is returning you a brand new instance (or otherwise consulting a `@Provides` method or component dependency). However, when that dependency is scoped, Dagger caches (["memoizes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) the result of the `@Provides` method such that it returns the same value rather than calling the method again or creating a new instance. Generally your root component is marked `@Singleton`, so marking your `ProfitStore` `@Singleton` means every request from that same root component will always return the same instance *even if* your ProfitStore has an `@Inject`-annotated constructor or a `@Provides` method that calls `new ProfitStore()`.

If you want multiple ProfitStore instances, you could just take the `@Singleton` annotation off of ProfitStore and create instances carefully. You'd then hand instances from one Fragment and ViewModel to another instead of using dependency injection. However, if your ProfitStore dependency graph is heavy, then that might be a reason to look to feature scopes to manage the network.

So all of that in mind, how do you use feature scopes? First, you'd need to create a [subcomponent](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/subcomponents.html) that you install inside your root component (or another subcomponent). The current idiomatic way to do that is to refer to the subcomponent in a module using [`@Module(subcomponents=/*...*/)`](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/Module.html#subcomponents--). Let's say the component is called an AccountSubcomponent, but you can call it AccountComponent or anything you'd like. You'll have to define the component, adding a module like AccountModule that would contain your `@Binds ProfitStore` or `@Provides ProfitStore` binding. On the component yourself you'd define a getter if needed for something like ProfitStore, as well as the `@Subcomponent.Factory` or `@Subcomponent.Builder` that would tell your root component how to create an instance of AccountSubcomponent. It might look like this:

```java
@Subcomponent(modules = {AccountModule.class})
public interface AccountSubcomponent {
  ProfitStore getProfitStore();

  @Subcomponent.Factory
  public interface Factory {
    AccountSubcomponent create();
  }
}
```

With that, now your root component can't directly inject a ProfitStore. It can inject an AccountSubcomponent.Factory, on which you can call `create()` to get an AccountSubcomponent, on which you can call `getProfitStore()` to get a ProfitStore. If that ProfitStore instance requires dependencies, it can fetch them from AccountSubcomponent or its parents (including your root component). This doesn't help much yet until you create your own [scope annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Scope.html): if you create `@AccountScope` (nearly identical to the `@RequestScope` in the documentation) and mark both your AccountSubcomponent and ProfitStore with it, then the scoping rules like `@Singleton` apply—but rather than matching the scope of your root component, now it matches the scope of your AccountSubcomponent. If you were to move your `inject(ProfitFragment)` method (see below) and the injectors/bindings for other Fragments/ViewModels that were conceptually in account scope, then they'd be able to inject ProfitStore and anything else you mark with `@AccountScope`. At that point you've successfully created a feature scope, specifically `@AccountScope`, as managed through an AccountSubcomponent instance you create exactly once per account.

### Fragment injectors, dagger.android, and Hilt

Above I mention `inject(ProfitFragment)`, which is one very basic way of using Dagger with Fragments. For Fragments, the Android system might [create the instance](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/android#why-dagger-on-android-is-hard) using a default FragmentFactory that calls its no-arg constructor. Consequently, it is more typical to get to a component and use [field injection](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#declaring-dependencies) to populate the `@Inject`-annotated fields.

`dagger.android` automates some of the boilerplate here by making it automatic to [create a possibly-scoped subcomponent](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/android/ContributesAndroidInjector.html) for a particular Activity subclass or Fragment subclass. The library also provides [base classes](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/android/support/DaggerFragment.html) which will automatically inject themselves after creation. By specifying modules on the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` binding or its manual equivalent,  you can customize what is inside that subcomponent. Rather than creating an AccountSubcomponent with `@AccountScope`, you could reuse your ProfitFragment's  subcomponent and mark ProfitStore with whatever scope annotation you put on your ProfitFragment's subcomponent—`@ProfitScope`, `@AccountScope`, `@ProfitFragmentScope`, or whatever you choose to call it. Fragment injection can be especially tricky in dagger.android because fragments can be children of other fragments, so reflecting your dependencies in your fragment structure can be challenging.

If you use Hilt, Dagger will inspect your build graph to automatically generate a Fragment component, which can be nice if you use libraries that need to integrate simultaneously with your app, activity, and fragment scopes. In that case, you'd use the same component for every Fragment you create regardless of parent/child relationship. This automation makes it a little trickier to install [custom components](https://dagger.dev/hilt/custom-components), but it can be done.

### An alternative

So if feature scopes are verbose and merging feature scopes with scope-managing Android DI frameworks is complex, what might a lightweight alternative look like? I'd mentioned above that you could just take scopes off of ProfitStore, create instances carefully, and hand them off between fragments and view models. If you have a limited set of accounts that could be in scope at any given time, you might just use some kind of state management solution that knows how to look up from a string key to a ProfitStore instance, creating one if it doesn't exist yet. This might look in your codebase like a `@Singleton ProfitStoreManager` that you inject wherever you need, so each ProfitFragment doesn't try to inject a ProfitStore but does consult the same ProfitStoreManager to cache and manage those ProfitStore instances. Such a solution isn't as pure and Dagger-integrated as the feature scope solution, but on balance it might be the simplest way to solve your problem—for now, at least.